# php form not working

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I cant get this to work properly. I know its something stupid but I cant find it.

```
<?php

$mailto   = "stormygurl73@yahoo.com";  
$name     = ucwords($_POST['name']); 
$subject  = $_POST['Contact form'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$message  = $_POST['message'];

    if(strlen($_POST['name']) < 1 ){
        echo  'email_error';
    }

  else if(strlen($email) < 1 ) {
        echo 'email_error';
    }

  else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", $email)) {
    echo 'email_error';
  }

    else if(strlen($message) < 1 ){
        echo 'email_error';

  } else {

    // NOW SEND THE ENQUIRY

    $email_message="\n\n" .
        "Name : " .
        ucwords($name) .
        "\n" .
        "Email : " .
        $email .
        "\n\n" .
        "Message : " .
        "\n" .
        $message .
        "\n" .
        "\n\n" ;

        $email_message = trim(stripslashes($email_message));
        mail($mailto, $subject, $email_message, "From: \"$vname\" <".$email.">\nReply-To: \"".ucwords($name)."\" <".$email.">\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() );

}
?>
```

Html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="main" style="padding:50px 0 0 0;">
    <form id="contact-form" action="sendemail.php" method="post">
      <h3>Get in touch</h3>
      <h4>Fill in the form below, and we'll get back to you within 24 hours.</h4>
      <div>
        <label>
          <span>Name: (required)</span>
          <input placeholder="Please enter your name" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          <span>Email: (required)</span>
          <input placeholder="Please enter your email address" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
        </label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>
          <span>Message: (required)</span>
          <textarea placeholder="Include all the details you can" tabindex="5" required></textarea>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit">Send Email</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <!-- /Form -->
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: "I cant get this to work properly" is not very useful for debugging. Please specify the error.

Comment: `I cant get this to work properly.` -- how are we supposed to know whats wrong with your form? What's the issue? Do you get any errors? How is the result you're getting different from the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

You must have the name attribute on your input-elements. The first one should have

```
 name="name"
```

and so on. You can read more about it here: [Variables From External Sources : HTML Forms (GET and POST)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've missed the attribute **name** `name='somename'` everywhere in your form fields. e.g.
This is what you have

```
<input placeholder="Please enter your name" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
```

This is what it should have been

```
<input name="name" placeholder="Please enter your name" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
```